# How to add files to svn that contain the `@` sign

Tags: macos, svn

In Mac and iOS development it is common to have files that contain the `@` sign (e.g. `MyImage@2x.png`).

If you want to check these kinds of files into a Subversion repository, it won't work:

```
% svn add MyImage.png
A  (bin)  MyImage.png
% svn add MyImage@2x.png
svn: warning: 'MyImage' not found
```

How can these files be added to `svn` repositories?

Answer (score 1):

If a file name contains `@`, Subversion expects it to be followed by a revision number.  Fortunately this is only enforced for the *last* `@` in the file name so the solution is to add a 2nd `@`:

```
% svn add MyImage@2x.png@
A  (bin)  MyImage@2x.png
```

This is actually a problem for any `svn` command, not just `svn add`.  For instance, this fails...

```
% svn status MyImage@2x.png
svn: syntax error parsing revision '2x.png'
```

...and the extra `@` works just as well to fix it:

```
% svn status MyImage@2x.png@
Path: MyImage@2x.png
Name: MyImage@2x.png
URL: . . .
```

Comment: Why downvote without care to comment??